# How to use eclipse swing designer in maven application?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, maven

i created a maven project with mvn archetype
and i was wondering how to use the eclipse GUI designer to create the swing interface.

1. Do i have to install a plugin for the GUI design first, if so, please suggest me a common used one.
2. Do i have to add extra configuration to the project ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install [WindowBuilder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html) then you can select `File` -> `New` -> `Other` -> `WindowBuilder` -> `Swing Designer` -> `Application Window` for example.

For more information see the [WindowBuilder Pro Quick Start](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/quick_start.html)